# If cauchy product converges then it must converge to AB.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation

I have been looking across the site but haven't found a proof of this statement:

> If $\sum_n{a_n}$ and $\sum_n{b_n}$ converge conditionally to A and B, then if the Cauchy product $\sum_n{d_n}$ converges it must converge to AB.

Its part of a question I'm working through where the hint is to use Abel's theorem and the ratio test. I guess by Abel's we know the Cauchy product is uniformly convergent on some region but how does that help us. I tried applying the ratio test for power series to the Cauchy product but I didn't get anything I could simplify (created power series with $a_n, b_n$ and $d_n$ as coefficients).

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $\sum a_n,\sum b_n$ converge, then the power series $\sum a_nx^n,\sum b_nx^n$ converge absolutely for $x\in (-1,1).$ What do you know about absolutely convergent series and Cauchy products?